# iOS Kudan project error in xcode libsystem_kernal.dylib error? Black screen when app loads

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, kudan

Trying to build The Kudan sample app for iOS out of Unity 5.5 But I keep getting an error in xcode during the loading phase on my iPad. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

libsystem_kernal.dylib
[Thread 42: signal SIGABRT](http://blob:http://imgur.com/92e0ce8d-26a2-4555-b3fb-531295f74dc6)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: When you run a project in Xcode, you should have a console log at the bottom of the window giving you some useful information. If you can tell us what that says at the time of the error, we can probably figure out what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue yesterday by adding ‘libiconv.2.tdb’ to my xcode project and removing libiconv.2.dylib.
I also had to add a ‘Privacy - Camera Usage Description’ with a short sentence explaining what the camera will be used for in the app to the info.plist in my project.

Thanks for your help!